# CSV/XLS to customised nested JSON/TSV in R

Tags: r, json, excel

I have a XLS file in the following format-- [XLS input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/278Tq.png). The first column is just for explanation of JSON elements. I want to convert the column headers into main elements and then the next 4 rows into nested JSON elements. The desired JSON file will look like this-- [JSON output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsDxX.png). I have tried string substitution in python which makes it easier but is there any way to do this in R?

XLS file -- [XLS input file Excel link](https://uvmoffice-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/dpanchol_uvm_edu/Edybpe9J6BtGi6p9mQYOMG4BnoD6e5aKBV--oL1lIDA-Pg?e=03Efw5)

Desired JSON output--

```js
{
  "MRI ID": {
    "Description": "MRI ID"
  },
  "Participant ID": {
    "Description": "Participant ID"
  },
  "Group": {
    "Levels": {
      "Case": "",
      "Control": "",
      "Cohort": ""
    }
  },
  "Gender": {
    "Levels": {
      "Male": "",
      "Female": "",
      "Other": ""
    }
  },
  "Age": {
    "Units": "Years"
  },
  "Vocab Raw Score WASI": {
    "Description": "Wechsler Abbreviated Scale Intellegence",
    "Units": "Raw Score"
  },
  "Handedness": {
    "Levels": {
      "Left": "",
      "Right": "",
      "Ambidextrous": ""
    }
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Drinks TLFB": {
    "Description": "Alcohol Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Drinks"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Drinking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Alcohol Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Average Drinks Per Drinking Day TLFB": {
    "Description": "Alcohol Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Average Drinks Per Drinking Day"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Non-Drinking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Alcohol Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Max Number of Drinks TLFB": {
    "Description": "Alcohol Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Heavy Drinking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Alcohol Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Cigarette Smoking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Nicotine Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Average Number of Cigarettes on Smoking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Nicotine Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Average Cigarettes"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Non-Cigarette Smoking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Nicotine Timeline Followback"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Max Number of Cigarettes TLFB": {
    "Description": "Nicotine Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Cigarettes"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Marajuana Smoking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Cannabis Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Last 60 Days Number of Non-Marajuana Smoking Days TLFB": {
    "Description": "Cannabis Timeline Followback",
    "Units": "Days"
  },
  "Matrix Reasoning Raw Score WASI": {
    "Description": "Wechsler Abbreviated Scale Intellegence",
    "Units": "Raw Score"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a link to a XLS file that contains data in the format you are considering. With this file, we could replicate your results.

Comment: @EmmanuelHamel I have added the link with Excel file